# My logs are filling up (on one of my Raspberry Pis)

Tags: raspbian

My logs are filling up, but only on one Raspberry Pi; the other is fine.

```
1.5G    daemon.log
1.9G    daemon.log.1

pi@raspberrypi /var/log $ tail daemon.log
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi dbus[1867]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 255
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi dbus[1867]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ModemManager' (using servicehelper)
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi modem-manager[21187]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi dbus[1867]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager'
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi NetworkManager[26603]: <info> modem-manager is now available
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi modem-manager[21187]: <warn>  Could not acquire the org.freedesktop.ModemManager service.#012  Message: 'Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.9" (uid=0 pid=26603 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager ") interface="org.freedesktop.ModemManager" member="EnumerateDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.ModemManager" (uid=0 pid=21187 comm="/usr/sbin/modem-manager ")'
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi NetworkManager[26603]: <info> the modem manager disappeared
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi NetworkManager[26603]: <info> trying to start the modem manager...
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi dbus[1867]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager' failed: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 255
Dec 19 06:25:41 raspberrypi dbus[1867]: [system] Activating service name='org.fpi@

pi@raspberrypi /var/log $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #285 PREEMPT Tue Nov 20 17:49:40 GMT 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

It seems like this has happened before: *[Debian Bug report logs - #568971
/usr/sbin/modem-manager: modem manager rapidly fills up daemon.log](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=568971)*.

Comment: Have you tried `invoke-rc.d dbus restart` or `sudo invoke-rc.d dbus reload`? This was one of the suggested fixes from the Debian bugs link you posted.

Comment: @VincentP Didn't work.  Ended up having to reboot.  Looks like probably the bug just has never been fixed.

Comment: Do you have LogRotate installed?

Comment: @Andrew Not unless it's standard.  It's obviously doing some kind of rotation.  I'll have to check it.  It's not the log rotation which caused the logs to fill up.  That was definitely a bug in the update process of dbus or whatever during a past apt-get.  I first started noticing space issues when apt-get refused to update and I did an apt-get clean, which obviously freed up some space.

Answer (score 1):

I have just restarted network-manager by:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart.
```

dbus-daemon, modem-manager and NetworkManager processes do not use [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) time as intensively.

It happened to me just after update and upgrade Raspbian through:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have not restarted the Raspberry Pi after that, but CPU usage returned to normal and the syslog file is not filled anymore...